# Correct use of Blockquote, q and cite?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, web-standards

Is this the correct use of `Blockquote`,  `q` and `cite`?

```
<p>
<blockquote>Type HTML in the textarea above, <q>and it will magically appear</q> in the frame below.
</blockquote>
<cite><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">refrence url</a>
</p>
```

Is use of `Blockquote`,  `q` semantically correct? or both are presentational element , so should not be used?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes. They are not presentational elements — `blockquote` represents a block quotation, `q` represents an inline quotation, and `cite` represents a reference to a name, work, standard, URL, etc.

You do have some [validation errors](https://validator.w3.org/check?fragment=%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%3Cblockquote%3EType+HTML+in+the+textarea+above,+%3Cq%3Eand+it+will+magically+appear%3C/q%3E+in+the+frame+below.%0D%0A%3C/blockquote%3E%0D%0A%3Ccite%3E%3Ca+href%3D%22http://stackoverflow.com%22%3Erefrence+url%3C/a%3E%0D%0A%3C/p%3E%0D%0A&doctype=Inline&prefill=1&prefill_doctype=xhtml10&group=0) that are fairly common with blockquote. A blockquote element cannot be inside a paragraph, and in HTML4 actually needs to *contain* paragraphs. The nesting of the `p` and `blockquote` elements in your fragment needs to be reversed.

The `blockquote` element (also the `q` element) can optionally have a `cite` attribute to specify a URI where the quote came from. [HTML5 says](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) user agents **should** make that link available to the user, and HTML4 doesn't say anything at all. I would include the URI both in the `cite` attribute and as an inline link, since browsers don't handle it.

Here's how I would write that fragment, with those revisions in mind:

```
<blockquote cite="http://stackoverflow.com">
  <p>Type HTML in the textarea above, <q>and it will magically
  appear</q> in the frame below.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>
  <cite><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">reference url</a></cite>
</p>
```

[Validate this fragment](https://validator.w3.org/check?fragment=%3Cblockquote+cite%3D%22http://stackoverflow.com%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cp%3EType+HTML+in+the+textarea+above,+%3Cq%3Eand+it+will+magically%0D%0A++appear%3C/q%3E+in+the+frame+below.%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%3C/blockquote%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%0D%0A++%3Ccite%3E%3Ca+href%3D%22http://stackoverflow.com%22%3Ereference+url%3C/a%3E%3C/cite%3E%0D%0A%3C/p%3E&doctype=Inline&prefill=1&prefill_doctype=xhtml10&group=0)

Comment: why we need to use different <p> to put <cite> why we can't put in same <p> after </blockquote>

Comment: A blockquote cannot be inside a paragraph. After you close the blockquote tag, you need to start a new paragraph.

Comment: but can't we put <cite> in <blockquote> after </p>?

Comment: Oh sure, you could. I don't really have an opinion on that matter. I just left it after the blockquote like you had it.

Comment: How did you made this tinyurl url to quickly give example of validation?

Comment: Change `method="post"` to `method="get"` in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @JitendraVyas, and anyone finding this question now, `cite` is now valid inside `blockquote`.  http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/

Answer (score 23):

The other answers on this page are out of date, but the question is still valid.

The `q` element semantically represents a quotation, and is an inline element. It should be used like so (ie. no block elements inside it):

```
<p>
   In the words of <cite>Charles Bukowski</cite> -  
   <q>An intellectual says a simple thing in a hard way. 
   An artist says a hard thing in a simple way.</q>
</p>
```

Another example:

```
<p>
    <q>This is correct, said Hillary.</q> is a quote from the 
    popular daytime TV drama <cite>When Ian became Hillary</cite>.
</p>
```

The `q` element should not be placed inside a `blockquote` element, as it would be redundant -- both denote a quote.

A `blockquote` is a block element, allowing other block elements to be placed inside:

```
  <blockquote>
    <p>My favorite book is <cite>At Swim-Two-Birds</cite>.</p>
    - <cite>Mike Smith</cite>
  </blockquote>
```

`<cite>` is an inline element representing the **title** of a body of work. Since the W3C and WHATWG have now agreed to work together, we have [one answer](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) as to what it may contain: The name of a book, a film, a TV show, a game, a song, a play, etc, etc.

It should NOT be a URL or an author's name (a URL can be added with a normal `a` element and an author is not a piece of work that you're citing).

This is a valid usage:

```
<figure>
 <blockquote>
  <p>The truth may be puzzling. It may take some work to grapple with.
  It may be counterintuitive. It may contradict deeply held
  prejudices. It may not be consonant with what we desperately want to
  be true. But our preferences do not determine what's true.</p>
 </blockquote>
 <figcaption>Carl Sagan, in "<cite>Wonder and Skepticism</cite>", from
 the <cite>Skeptical Inquirer</cite> Volume 19, Issue 1 (January-February
 1995)</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: awesome explanation!

Comment: The link to the W3C specifiation now forwards to the WHATWG page, since this is now the accepted and only specification (see https://www.w3.org/html/). In other words: The WHATWG example is the officially correct one, and the cite element should not contain an authors name.

Comment: @makkabi Thanks! Updated

Answer (score 6):

You could consider `BLOCKQUOTE` analogous to a `DIV` and `Q` analogous to `SPAN`.

Recommended usage is to enclose large quotes in `BLOCKQUOTE` and small, single line or sentence quotes in `Q`.

```
<blockquote>
    <p>This is a big quote.</p>
    <p>This is the second paragraph with a smaller <q>quote</q> inside</p>
</blockquote>
```

Cite is an attribute on either which merely points to the source.

Answer (score 4):

Using attributes such as the `cite` attribute of the `blockquote` or `q` doesn't make it easily displayable (without JS or tricky CSS) and so does not address the aim of displaying a reference link easily. [It is now conforming](http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/) to include `cite` (and/or `footer`) *into* `blockquote` to specify the source, either textually of through a URL, of the quote, like below :

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.” </p>
  <cite><a href="http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/faq.html">Donald Knuth: Notes on the van Emde Boas construction of priority deques: An instructive use of recursion, March 29th, 1977</a>
</blockquote>
```

Note that :

- cases of `cite` that are part of the quote contents (not the source reference) are also deemed quite rare, and should be handled through a differenciating class on the relevant `cite` subtag)
- Regarding `q`, it is indeed aimed to quote inline, but it is more likely to be used outside of blockquotes (quotes into quotes are quite rare).

Answer (score 1):

The semantic (and valid) use of the `<cite>` element is still under debate even if *"in HTML5, use of this element to mark a person's name is no longer considered semantically appropriate."*

You'll find a very detailed and useful article about "`<blockquote>`, `<q>` and `<cite>`" here:

http://html5doctor.com/blockquote-q-cite/

Comment: Another good read about the topic (with sample markup) is the A List Apart's article and Gist you could find here: 

http://alistapart.com/blog/post/more-thoughts-about-blockquotes-than-are-strictly-required
and here:
https://gist.github.com/murtaugh/4489740

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/blockquote-q-cite/ now (2014-09-29) states, "The definitions of cite and blockquote in HTML have changed. For the latest advice on using these elements refer to [cite and blockquote – reloaded](http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/)"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_q_cite.asp), "cite" is an **attribute** of q - and is not well supported at that.