# Differences between <q> and <blockquote>

Tags: html, semantic-markup

There are several articles about this topic but I'm not able to understand the relevant difference between `<q>` and `<blockquote>`. The spec seems to have changed for blockquote [link](http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/). It seems that long quotations are reserved for blockquote and inline quotation for `<q>`.

What do they mean with inline quotations?

Does one need to have the name of an author?

For example: what if the quote is of a company and its one long sentence. I would use `<q>` but I would not know exactly how to defend that point with arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct use of Blockquote, q and cite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205159/correct-use-of-blockquote-q-and-cite)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just see their definitions:

- [`q` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element):

  > […] some phrasing content quoted from another source
- [`blockquote` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element):

  > […] a section that is quoted from another source

The last part is the same ("quoted from another source"), so they only differ in "phrasing content" vs. "section".

`q` can only contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (and it can only be used where such phrasing content is expected). `blockquote` can only contain [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#flow-content-1) (and it can only be used where such flow content is expected). In that sense, they are similar to [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (~ `q`) and [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) (~ `blockquote`).

Some other differences:

Note that `blockquote` is a [sectioning root](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#sectioning-root), which means that any headings or sectioning elements it may contain will not be part of the document’s [outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#outlines). `q` can’t contain headings or sectioning elements in the first place.

Note that you MUST NOT use any quotation marks when using `q` (not before, not inside, not after), because user agents should add them automatically. There is no such restriction for `blockquote` (however, it’s probably unlikely that you’d need some for block quotes).

Answer (score 10):

`<blockquote>` is a block level element like div. Which means that it will start at a new line if you put it in a document flow.
For example, if my markups are:

```
 Henry Ford said <blockquote>Most people spend more time and energy going around problems than in trying to solve them.</blockquote> in the 20th century
```

They will be shown on browsers like this
[image: blockquote Example]

`<q>` is an inline element like span.  So if my markups are

```
 Henry Ford said <q>Most people spend more time and energy going around problems than in trying to solve them.</q> in the 20th century
```

The result will be

[image: q example]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is more redirected the difference between them semantically. When should I use one or the other... Is then the difference only depending on its length?

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero No. If you want your quote continues where the text ends, then use <q>. Otherwise, use <blockquote> Have a look at the images.

Comment: This means that there is no semantical difference, only visual?

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero Yes

Answer (score 4):

`<blockquote>` is block level element, normally it starts and end with new line when displayed in the browser.
`<q>` is inline element,normally it displays without line break.

Block elements stand on their own; inline elements goes with the flow.