# HTML-tag to annotate the origin of a section?

Tags: html, seo, google-search, semantic-markup

Google don't like it when you use same content across multiple sites, according to some.

Is there any way to annotate/tag a block of content with the "source".

Something like an attribute:

```
<div original-content="http://some.url">
```

The purpose is solely to let Google that we have duplicated the content (I.e. not as part of a search ranking strategy). Search engines could then use this information somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out:

http://searchengineland.com/google-creates-metatags-to-help-id-original-news-sources-56115

Looks like the meta tag you want is

```
meta name=”original-source” content=”[url]”
```

However it looks like that is only for an entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the canonical tag, which tells the web engine crawler that the text is duplicated from the original website.

**Example:**

Place this in the header of your HTML page (in the duplicated content page)

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.original-website.com" />
```

Reference: [Canonical URL Tag - The Most Important Advancement in SEO Practices Since Sitemaps](http://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps)

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML has no such element or attribute.

If you quote the content (in a [`q`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element) [or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21885256/1591669) [`blockuote`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) element), you could use the `cite` attribute. But you must not use these elements for anything other than quotes.

If the whole document is duplicated (or is a subset), you could use the [`canonical` link type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596). But [you must not](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54029/17633) use this if only part of the document is duplicated while the other parts are different.