# HTML tag to mention information source?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

For example - I have a website with an attached blog. I post contents in the blog(A). And I have a personal blog(B). I can alter only the `body` tags.

Is there a tag where I can mention A as my information source?

Comment: Related (not duplicate, because it’s asking about a way supported by Google Search): [HTML-tag to annotate the origin of a section?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26740200/1591669)

Answer (score 1):

#### If quoting

If you quote the content, you could use the [`blockquote` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) and its [`cite` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#attr-blockquote-cite):

> […] address […] may be cited in the `cite` attribute.

But if you don’t quote the content, you can’t use that.

#### If not quoting

By using the [`bookmark` link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-bookmark), you could convey that the permalink of the post is the one from the source blog. For that to work the post must be in an `article` element, or in the `body` (not within any other sectioning element).

While the `canonical` link type [can also be used on `a` elements](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) (so you could specify it in the `body`), it’s only appropriate to use it if you don’t allow comments for the blog posts. Otherwise (as soon as you get a comment for one post, and not the very same for your other post, too) the content is no longer the same or a superset of the other one, which means that `canonical` must not be used.